# JavaScript array to dictionary conversation based on count

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, array-map

I have a array like below

```
 data = [A,B,B,B,C,C,A,B]
```

How can I convert into dictionary like below format.

```
  data = [
  {
    name: "A",
    y: 2
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    y: 4
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    y: 2
  }
]
```

Have to convert elements as names and count of the elements as value to y.

I've a library which accepts only in that format.
Not able to do, stuck in the middle

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Are you able to get rid of the array and just have an object such as `var obj = {'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 2}`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function convert(data){
  var myMap = {}
  data.forEach(el => myMap[el] = myMap[el] != undefined ? myMap[el] + 1 : 1);
  return Object.keys(myMap).map(k => {return {name: k, y: myMap[k]}})
}

console.log(convert(['A','B','B','B','C','C','A','B']))
```

Comment: I would call your variable something other than a function name. `myMap` would work...

Comment: @Matt I was thinking the same. Done.

Answer (score 2):

```js
data = ['A','B','B','B','C','C','A','B'];

var res = Array.from(new Set(data)).map(a =>
  ({name:a, y: data.filter(f => f === a).length}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

use array.reduce:

```js
data = ['A','B','B','B','C','C','A','B'];

var res = data.reduce((m, o) => {
  var found = m.find(e => e.name === o);
  found ? found.y++ : m.push({name: o, y: 1});
  return m;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```